# Appcelerator Titanium: Set Android.SearchView.iconifiedByDefault to false does not work if it is in actionBar?

Tags: android, appcelerator, searchview, appcelerator-titanium

When I create a searchView and set iconifiedByDefault: false, it automatically loads into the search bar (ie. prompts for text immediately instead of having to click on the magnifying glass first).

```
search = Ti.UI.Android.createSearchView({
    hintText: "Search",
    iconifiedByDefault: false
});

$.index.add(search);
$.index.open();
```

However, when I add the SearchView into the ActionBar with iconifiedByDefault:false, the keyboard comes out but I still see a magnifying glass. I added the SearchView into the ActionBar like this:

$.index.activity.onCreateOptionsMenu = function(e) {
    var menu = e.menu;

```
if (Ti.Platform.name == 'android' && Ti.Platform.Android.API_LEVEL > 11) {
    var menuItem = menu.add({
        title: 'Table Search',
        actionView : search,
        icon: (Ti.Android.R.drawable.ic_menu_search ? Ti.Android.R.drawable.ic_menu_search : "my_search.png"),
        showAsAction: Ti.Android.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM | Ti.Android.SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW
    });
}
```

}

Any ideas why this won't work if I put the SearchView into the ActionBar? Thanks.

On Titanium SDK 5.2.

Comment: I've looked and worked with this a bit - just an FYI to anyone still searching. I don't think it can be done. If searchview is in the actionbar, the searchbox can't be opened by default.

Comment: Do you have an example of an Android app that does have it open by default? Because I think it's by design that it's not.

Comment: In a particular window, yeah. For example as you're scrolling through songs in spotify, the search bar is open at the top. But for the overall application, you're definitely right; it's usually not open by default. At least I haven't seen it open by default. I guess a hack would be to simply build a top:0 View at the top of the page instead of using ActionBar, right? Thanks.

Comment: I think that's the only way indeed. Looking at the Spotify app's hamburger icon that view is not an ActionBar but a custom view.